# protoRPC: returning dict

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

How does one return a `dict` like object through `protoRPC` ?

I tried using the `FieldList` to no avail.  I only see the following field definitions:

```
       'IntegerField',
       'FloatField',
       'BooleanField',
       'BytesField',
       'StringField',
       'MessageField',
       'EnumField',
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two scenarios:

**1) Your `dict` has a well-defined schema:** This is the best use case for ProtoRPC and if possible you should try to fit it into a schema. In this case, you would use a `MessageField` with some `Message` class that matches the schema in your dictionary.

For example, instead of

```
{'amount': 31, 'type': 'fish', mine: False}
```

you could define

```
from protorpc import messages
class MyCatch(messages.Message):
  amount = messages.IntegerField(1)
  type = messages.StringField(2)
  mine = messages.BooleanField(3)
```

and then use this message definition in a field via

```
messages.MessageField(MyCatch, index, ...)
```

**2) Your `dict` does not have a well-defined schema:** In this case you can use `json` to dump your dictionary to a string and request `ensure_ascii=True` to make sure the return type is a bytes (`str`) object. Then you can just use a `BytesField`.

For example:

```
import json

class MyMessage(messages.Message):
   some_dict = messages.BytesField(1)

my_dict = {'amount': 31, 'type': 'fish', mine: False}
message = MyMessage(some_dict=json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=True))
```

The use of `ensure_ascii` is optional as `True` is the default, but this may change depending on your environment.

Instead you could use `pickle` to serialize your dictionary. The method `pickle.dumps` always outputs ASCII/binary, so by swapping out `json.dumps` for `pickle.dumps` and dropping the `ensure_ascii=True`, you'd have the same outcome.

Comment: has something changed in the API?  When I do this, I get a base64 encoded string on the client side.  When decode the string I get the JSON back.  Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using `messages.BytesField`?

Comment: Yes I am @bossylobster.  Here is my code snippet.

Definition

    return CompanyConfigResponse( status = 'OK',
                                  name = cmp.name,
                                  barcodetype=cmp.barcodetype,
                    configs =  json.dumps(cinfo,ensure_ascii=True))

Comment: Here is my definition

  configs = messages.BytesField(5, required=False)

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior of a `BytesField`. How else would you websafe encode bytes?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create a custom `JsonField` like this :

```
In  [1]: class JsonField(messages.StringField):
             type = dict
```

You can then use it as any other field :

```
In  [2]: class MyMessage(messages.Message):
             data = JsonField(1)

In  [3]: m = MyMessage(data={"foo": "bar"})

In  [4]: m.data
Out [4]: {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first option in the approved answer, we can add a parameter repeated=True, so we'll have a list of json as the answer. I checked about it at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/overview?hl=en#Defining_the_Response_Message

Answer (score 0):

A bit involved, but I have a recipe for something quite close to a dict implementation for `protorpc`: https://gist.github.com/linuxluser/32d4a9c36ca0b8715ad4

It is restricted to using string-only keys and simple (not nested) values. But if your data fits in that category, this solution should work well.

The idea has 2 parts:

1. Create a new field type `MultiField` that can hold an arbitrary value type.
2. Create a dict-like type `MapField` that stores key-value pairs in a  list of `MultiField` types.

You use it like so:

```
import messages
import mapfield

class MyMessage(messages.Message):
  some_dict = mapfield.MapField(1)


my_message = MyMessage(some_dict={"foo": 7, "bar": False, "baz": 9.2, "qux": "nog"})
```

It's only a start. Probably could be better. Improvements are welcomed. :)